# cxf client from WSDL with empty targetNamespace

Tags: jaxb, cxf, jax-ws, cxf-codegen-plugin, cxf-client

I am using cxf client to consume a web-service that has a targetNamespace="" in the WSDL's XSD definition.
The CXF client seems to append a namespace of ns2 to the each request as shown below.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/“>
 <soap:Body>
        <ns2:ReadSubscriberRequest xmlns:ns2="http://www.x.com/TFProvisioning/“>
           <SubscriberId>9999</SubscriberId>
        </ns2:ReadSubscriberRequest>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Why does cxf add ns2 namespace?
The ns2 namespace is unfamiliar to soap-service and therefore it throws an fault: Cannot find the declaration of element 'ns2:ReadSubscriberRequest'

How do I prevent cxf from adding a ns2 namespace reference in cases were targetNamespace=""

Comment: can you post some code of the client ...are you using package-info.java?